# Why filelist is empty even after uploading images

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to upload multiple images of a model(say ChannelPostImages) to django view.But when i'm using request.FILES.getlist it's empty.

```
 <form method="POST" id="uploadimages" action="/Channels/SMusic/ChannelAdminPost/34/">
{% csrf_token %}
<input id="imager" type="file" name="Images"accept="image/*" multiple="True">
<button class="submitter">POST</button>
</form>
```

while my view function is as follows:-

```
 def ChannelAdminPoster(request,channelname,userid):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        files = request.FILES.getlist('Images')
        print(files)
        for f in files:
            print(f)
        objec=get_object_or_404(channel,ChName=channelname)

    else:
        return redirect('home')
```

It should be printing path of images on command prompt.But it is showing an empty query.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing  enctype="multipart/form-data" .

```
<form method="POST" id="uploadimages" action="/Channels/SMusic/ChannelAdminPost/34/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```